# Typescript type error after filtering array to remove unwanted type

Tags: typescript

In typescript, I have an array of type `Array<string|undefined`, and I wish to filter out the undefined values and assign that resulting array a variable of type `Array<string>`, but I get a type error. How can I achieve this?

e.g.

```js
const a: Array<string|undefined> = ['a',undefined,'b'];
const b: Array<string> = a.filter(Boolean); // ERROR
```

Error

> Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Answer (score -1):

```
const a: Array<string|undefined> = ['a',undefined,'b'];

const b: Array<string> = a.filter(item => item);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I've taken your meaning. (a) Aren't filter functions supposed to return a boolean (not an 'item')? (b) My filter function does return a boolean. (c) Your answer appears to produce the exact same error as my faulty implementation.